# Polar scatter plot doesn't plot last column

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bunch of data that I want plot on a polar scatter plot (Matplotlib) nevertheless, I don't know why last column isn't being plotted on the correct site.

Code is the following one:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
c = ax.scatter(ang2,dis)
```

ang2 and dis are:

```
dis = [[0. 0.68922638  0.83123282]
[ 0.68922638 0. 0.79794799]
[0.83123282 0.79794799 0.]]
ang2 = [[0. 129.99715946 67.5073881 ]
[309.99715946 0. 17.50394597]
[247.5073881 197.50394597 0.]]
```

and the result is

[image]

As you see angles, 67.5 and 17.5 are incorrectly plot. I wonder know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Plt plot takes radians as standard input. I have taken the same values and converted it to radians for you and ran it. Seems to be correct now.

```
>>> ang4 = [[0.0, 2.268878450817094, 1.178226191766639], [5.410471104406887, 0.0, 0.3055014892676926], [4.319818845356432, 3.4470941428574857, 0.0]]
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
>>> ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
>>> ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
>>> c = ax.scatter(ang4,dis)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: New Plot]

You can simply run your values through math.radians or any other converter.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has helped you. Thanks